# VBA Lotus Notes sender email address as CC

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes

I created a makro in excel to send all TODOs to the responsible people. Now I want to add the sender address into the CC. I know how to set the CC but I don't know how to get the current sender address.

```
Set session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set db = session.GETDATABASE("", "")
Call db.OPENMAIL
Set doc = db.CREATEDOCUMENT
Call doc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("CopyTo", strEmail)
```

I think it should work with the notes session, but I didn't find any method for this.

Comment: did you try ´doc.GetItemValue("From")´ ?

Comment: yes, I get an empty string

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `NotesSession.UserName()`.  This is Notes mail you are sending. You don't need a full SMTP-style address with the @ and the DNS domain name. You can just put the user's Notes username in an addressing field and the Domino router will do the lookup and it will just work.

The above is true as long as (a) the server that you have established the session with is either the user's home mail server, a member of the same Notes domain (which is not the same thing as a DNS domain), or a member of a Notes domain that includes the user's Notes domain as part of its Directory Assistance (or its cascading address book list if it's using 20-year-old configurations), and (b) the username is unique within the above scope.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try tomorrow :). I already used the username for greetings.

Answer (score 0):

another suggestion, copy sender from last sent mail, to test

```
Set view = db.GetView("(($Sent))")
Set sentdoc = View.GetLastDocument
sender=sentdoc.getItemValue("From")
```

Comment: An error occures on line 'Set sentdoc = View.GetLastDocument'. Runtime error '91': Object variable or With block not set

Comment: view variable is probably empty, try with db.getview("$Sent")

Answer (score 0):

The way I automated Lotus Notes and sending emails was using this site below:

[Send files using Lotus Notes](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/notes/notes7.htm)

The area you want to pay attention to is at the bottom, which takes "noDocument" and adds the relevant titles "Subject", "to", "Sendto" etc.

'Add values to the created e-mail main properties.

```
 With noDocument
    .Form = "Memo"
    .SendTo = vaRecipients
    .CopyTo = vaCopyTo
    .Subject = stSubject
    .Body = vaMsg
    .SaveMessageOnSend = True
    .PostedDate = Now()
    .Send 0, vaRecipients
  End With
```

Comment: I already could sending mail automated, but didnt know how to get full email address

Comment: The full email doesn't need to be populated. You just need the "First name" and "Last Name", afterwards, Lotus will auto-populate the names with the best match, so make sure they are spelled correctly....otherwise it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NotesSession.userName()` to get the current username. If you really want the full email address you might also be able use `@namelookup` formula.

However, I would stay away from accessing notes via COM as it does not work on 64bit and IBM couldn't care less about it. I had several excel files which used this handy technique, but they are all broken since we moved to 64bit. Check this old kb https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291

Comment: This is true. The Notes client is 32 bit, and IBM does not support COM classes for access to it from 64 bit code. That's not a problem when you are writing in VB and can build your code to run as 32 bit, but it is a problem when you are writing in VBA and your code needs to run inside a 64 bit Excel program.